# java - Object and ".class" use

Tags: java, object

I am a newbie and I have covered all the basic concepts of Java. Till now, I have come across examples where object references are created using Object class and using the ".class" syntax.

I tried searching for explanation on how these 2 concepts are used and I am not getting a clear picture.

All I see is, yes we can create a reference to Object. **But how/what is this reference used for?**

And for **.class** syntax, I keep seeing the term 'Reflection' but what really happens when I use this syntax on an exsting class like **existingclass.class**? And is it just to use the methods/data with in the <**existingclass**> without creating an instance/object?

Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very vague and confusing. Perhaps if you post some code that you're having trouble with, or what it is that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A reference to `Object` can point to *any* object; it can point to different kinds of objects at different times. It's a good parameter type for a method when you want to pass in any kind of object, and it's a good return type when you want to be able to return any kind of object.
2. The notation *ClassName*`.class` returns an instance of `java.lang.Class` which represents *ClassName*. For every class loaded in the Java virtual machine, there is a `java.lang.Class` object to represent that class. As to what it's good for -- it's only good for fairly advanced, magical stuff like writing code that asks what methods a class has, or creating an instance of a class when all you have is the name of the class typed in by a user or read from a file.

   Also, when you learn about *threads*, you'll see that the class object has a special purpose wih respect to static methods; this need not concern you now. As a beginning Java programmer, you'll have no need to use it; someday, though, you may.

Answer (score 1):

The word `Java` has three meanings:

1. A programming language;
2. a virtual machine(JVM) specification;
3. and the run-time environment for Java application.

From a programming language's perspective, it defines grammar and syntax. It gives instruction on how to use the language. To have a knowledge of the `.class`, you'd better refer to the JVM specification(yep, it's already beyond the language scope).

Roughly speaking, your program is thoroughly compiled into `.class` file in byte code format including superclass name inherented, interfaces implemented, and, the most important, compiled code, etc..

When running a program, all the `.class`s contribute to its completion should be loaded into JVM. IIRC, classes are loaded the first time they are referenced by your program, instead of the moment program going to run, e.g. in the import instruction or by a direct `.class` reference in your code.

So to answer your question, the `.class` syntax is not only used to refer class information, e.g. method definitions or static variables, but also enforce JVM load specific class. (If you are familiar with JDBC or have a chance play with it in the future,  you will find `.class` syntax can be used to enforce loading a database driver)